# FileOpenPickerUI: prevent deleting file when user clicks on image in the basket

Tags: uwp, fileopendialog, fileopenpicker

I'm using **Windows.Storage.Pickers.Provider.FileOpenPickerUI** to implement an UWP app that allows taking multiple pictures.

The thumbnails automatically appear in a basket on the bottom of the screen (see screenshot below). When the user clicks on a thumbnail, the file gets deleted and **FileRemoved** event triggered.

This is confusing and frustrating for the user, because the basket looks like a gallery where the user can view images by clicking on the thumbnail.

Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: With your screenshot, it seemed to be a windows 8.1 universal app. If it‘s windows 10 UWP app, the [FileOpenPicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker#Windows_Storage_Pickers_FileOpenPicker_PickMultipleFilesAsync) shows like this: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AoI4pKdRYn8KnG_EPB-ym9n9ibXq

Comment: Yes, it runs Windows 8.1. Unfortunately, the client is a large organization, so I can't easily change that.

Comment: @Peter Unfortunately, It's by design. You cannot change it.

Comment: Thanks, it's good to know, at least.